# There's an easy way to apply a shortest path alghoritm in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dijkstra

I have a series of point (x,y) linked by a path. There's an easy way in objective c to apply something like a Dijkstra shortest path alghoritm in order to know the shortest path among two variable points of these?
The real problem is i have an image with a series of locations on it and the coordinate of all these location. Now i need the user to choose two of this location and getting the shortest path between the location choosen.

Comment: You are going to need some data structure to represent the graph held in the image.

Comment: i can use an array to contain point that are couple of numbers, but for the remaining... i was guessing if there's an easiest way then implementing the alghoritm by myself :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do this. Here there is a perfect implementation of the algorithm. Hope it helps someone.

https://github.com/snyderp/PESGraph

Comment: any demo or example to use this library?

Comment: Download it, there's some example inside. It's pretty simple to use!

Comment: Yes, there's a complete xcodeproject in there. Open it, open the folder PesGraph Test and take a look to PESGraphTests.m :)

Comment: no there isn't as far as i know. You have to take a look to the code, understand what it does and then use it in your application. When i used it the first time i was pretty a newbie and it wasn't so difficult to me. Takes only some time to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to find an algorithm online in C or C++ and manipulate it to input your list type, and output the shortest path point list, that way you dont have to implement the actual algorithm, just manipulate a set of code that already exists.

Comment: seems simple ^^' surely i will try something like this but my fear is that it take less time to manipulate a c code in objective c than trying to implement it by myself...