# dijkstra's algorithm on iOS

Tags: ios, graph, dijkstra

I am tracking locations and their connections to other locations.
I keep locations in an NSArray while each location is represented as a Dictionary.  Each location has Dictionary has the attributes (locationName, Connections, latitude, longitude) where Connections is an Array of other locations this location is connected TO (not from).  I use lat/lon and a Haversine algorithm to determine the distance between two points.

NEXT, I would like to use dijkstra's shortest path algorithm to find the shortest path between a source and destination location (source and destination are selected by the user)

This is not for commercial use and does not need to support hundreds or thousands of locations.

I am looking for some objective C code that will perform this search.

Comment: We won't write your code for you, but if you provide us with what you've got, we can give suggestions.

Comment: I understand. Passing in the parameters source, destination, and LocationArray I want to return the shortest path (in terms of distance) between them.  Each connection is 'one-way', A---->B means that you can get to B from A, but it is not implicit that you can get from B to A unless explicitly defined in the B location Dictionary.  I thnk this may get more confusing if I share my current broken code.  This portion (dijkstra's algorithm) needs a rewrite.

Comment: Go ahead and share it (bad code doesn't mean you're a bad programmer, it just means you're learning).  Wikipedia has a great pseudocode example.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: Thanks Kittens.  I just think focusing on what I have will be a distraction right now.  I have a recursive version that is the wrong approach - I did this before I discovered the existence of dijkstra's.  So it is home-grown.  It needs to be ditched and rewritten, which is where I am now.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google found some objective-c code at [snyderp / PESGraph](https://github.com/snyderp/PESGraph) which says

> PESGraph is a simple graph implementation for Foundation.kit that
>   allows for greating structures of nodes and paths, and then finding
>   the shortest path between them.  It includes unit tests that also
>   provide some examples of how to use the code.

Also this question was previously asked on SO [theres-an-easy-way-to-apply-a-shortest-path-alghoritm-in-objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737580/theres-an-easy-way-to-apply-a-shortest-path-alghoritm-in-objective-c) and the solution pointed to the same git repository that I found through google.

Comment: There is no sample code included with the PESGraph repo. Do you manage to actually use it at the end?

Answer (score 2):

I had to write my own sample code, because I wasn't able to find any good and working example. You can check it here:

https://github.com/aolszak/AOShortestPath

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: [mj-dijkstra](https://github.com/dmitrikozlov/mj-dijkstra)
A graph representation is a NSDictionary or an object that behaves like a dictionary.