# shortest path drawing between two stores in a same mall

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, mapkit

The requirement is , suppose a person is went to the mall and he want to go to particular store from his current locations, So the app will give him the two options to choose ,current store and the intended store , after selecting this two options, the map will pop there showing the shortest path between selected stores, that stores might be on diff. floors . 
As no lat long can be use because the stores are in the same mall how could i do this, some body please help me.

Comment: One store is a game store and the other a liquor store right?  There are no shoe or clothes stores involved are there?

Comment: @trojanfoe : any kind of stores could be there , as the stores are in the mall and the mall has all kind of stores.

Comment: Ahh - what a shame.  This is not a trivial problem.  You need detailed   model information about the Mall and need to devise a complex path-finding algorithm.  Good luck.

Comment: @trojanfoe : devise a complex path-finding algorithm , And you says not a trivial problem, It is the problem buddy. what logic should be used to full fill this requirement.

Comment: No idea, but it similar to the path-finding used by bots in games like Quake etc.  You might want to look at that code to get an idea of the problems involved.

Comment: There are common pathfinding algorithms that can be used if you have a map of the mall. This question implies that, in the real world, you *would* have a map.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan : will you please tell me the names of some of such a algorithms, so that i can go through them.

Comment: How about [this](http://bit.ly/XrZG8Q)

Comment: @Matthias: That was kind of my point, yeah…

Comment: @Matthias : i know this real world algorithms, but i have not yet played with such a implementation of algorithms in the objective-c, I want some example or some guid so that i can proceed.

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to create a weighted graph representing the mall:

- Nodes being the stores and path intersections (i.e escalators between floors)
- Edges being the paths connecting them
- Weights of the edges being the distance/time to walk between nodes

Then implement something like [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path between two nodes (stores).

The solution could then be drawn as an overlay onto a map of the mall.

This is an example of a [Shortest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem), which is a subset of the classic [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

This thread has a link to objective c code that may help: [Easy way to apply a shortest path alghoritm in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756237/1124373)